# Upward Orientation of Surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider a surface given by the graph of $z = g(x,y)$.  In my multivariable calc book (Stewart 7E), in section 16.7 they state the following.

> Associate with the surface a natural orientation given by the unit normal vector
>   $$
> \mathbf{n} = \frac{-\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \mathbf{i} -\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)^2}}
> $$
>   Since the $\mathbf{k}$-component is positive, this gives an *upward* orientation of the surface.

Consider the part of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ in the first octant.  The natural orientation points outward from the origin.  For the points on this surface in the $xy$-plane, why would the unit normal have any $\mathbf{k}$-component, let alone a positive one?

Consider instead the part of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ where $x>0$, $y>0$ and $z<0$.  The natural orientation still points outward from the origin.  Why would the unit normal have a positive $\mathbf{k}$-component?  It seems like the unit normals below the $xy$-plane should have a *negative* $\mathbf{k}$-component.

Comment: The sphere is not the graph of any function $z=g(x, y)$.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese Edited my question.  Thanks.

Comment: Steward is just giving a way to $always$ construct an orientation on the graph of a function.  In this case, the word 'natural' has a specific mathematical meaning (similar to 'canonical').  You can certainly define some other orientation on the lower half-sphere if it suits your needs.

Comment: It's to make it so that if you had some surface given by $g(x,y)$, the normal would point perpendicularly from the surface and upwards along the positive $z$-axis, instead of downwards along the negative $z$-axis